# Generate Personised QR Code in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, qr-code

Just see this WordPress plugins.

https://www.unitag.io/qrcode

And amazed, Love to do in Objective c.

Just give me any hint, How to achive it.

Also checked this [library](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/) It works great with colorful QR code. Put some efforts to add image, But it went to mess up code.

For scanning i have did with **AVFoundation** Library. I can scan personised QR code which generate by above WordPress plugin.

Please do needful, if anyone have hands on it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why it is -1 ??? Who have did it ?? I am not asking to do my stuff. I ask only for hints which mentioned in Question..

Comment: what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: @Ours-Polaire Have you work anytime on QR code generator for objective c ?